# Why Wont It Console.log The Result?

Tags: javascript, logging, console

It should say `Bob Miller` in the console

But instead it says `Undefined Undefined`

I would really appreciate if anyone helped me out on this.

```
<body bgcolor='000000'>
   <center>
       <input placeholder='Enter First Name' value='Bob' class='firstName'>
       <input placeholder='Enter Last Name' value='Miller' class='lastName'>
   </center>
</body>
<script>
   firstname = document.getElementsByClassName('firstName').value;
   lastname = document.getElementsByClassName('lastName').value;
   result = firstname + ' ' + lastname;
   console.log(result);
</script>
```

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns an HTMLDomArray. You will need to do 
`document.getElementsByClassName('className')[0].value` since the array has no value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**document.getElementsByClassName**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) method returns an *array like object*, not a single one. You need to access the `[0]th` item in that object as accessing arrays with index, and then get its value. Also declare your variables explicitly using `var/let/const` keywords.

```js
var firstname = document.getElementsByClassName('firstName')[0].value;
// ---------------------------------------------------------^^^------
var lastname = document.getElementsByClassName('lastName')[0].value;
// -------------------------------------------------------^^^------
var result = firstname + ' ' + lastname;
console.log(result);
```

```html
<input placeholder='Enter First Name' value='Bob' class='firstName'>
<input placeholder='Enter Last Name' value='Miller' class='lastName'>
```